# realistic jumping box2d - configuration of variables

Tags: box2d, physics, libgdx, game-physics, jbox2d

I'm still working on my Jump 'n' Run and have already solved the "can I jump" question.

My Question is now, how should I configure the *Gravity*, the *Timesteps*, the *Fixturesize*, the *applied Impulse* and the *Fixturedensity* for the most realistic result?.
The Fixturesize is now at 230x140 and can't be changed cause I need the pixelexact size for debugging. What can be changed is:

**Gravity**(10),

**Timesteps**(Deltatime*4);

**applied Impulse**(1000000);

**Fixturedensity**(0,002);

And why do I need an Impulse of 1 (!) million to move a current mass of 65kg?

Comment: Try these values, and if you don't like how the results look, adjust them one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not use pixelexact sizes, this will make the engine perform and act poorly.  It's in mks (meters-kilograms-seconds).  A 230x140 meter object is a little large.  Also object speed is capped at around 200 m/s, so you won't get that moving very fast.  If you need help with transforming, take a look at the OOBViewportTransform class, which is provided in the common package.

The impulse and density only matter in relation to other objects.  So you might want to create a level first, and then test how your character interacts.  Starting with densities of 1 is usually fine.  You generally don't want to make either too high.

Comment: Thank you :) That was kind of what i was looking for ;)

Comment: there is no OOBViewportTransform class in LibGDX :/

Comment: i have the class Box2ddebugrenderer in which i run the method: "render(world, matrix4)"... are the objects scaling up, if i change the matrix4? now, the matrix4 is set to "cam.combined". What do I need to change? ;)